# Unity Header Attribute not working properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

Code:

```
[Header("Player's Survival Stats")]
public float maxHealth, maxHunger, maxThirst;
public float thirstIncreaseRate, hungerIncreaseRate;
private float health, hunger, thirst;
```

[Inspector Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyMn8.png)

The single Header is shown multiple times... why is it so?
I just want one Header title named **"Player's Survival Stats"**

Comment: Because it is treated individually for each of `maxHealth, maxHunger, maxThirst;`

Answer (score 1):

Split your variable declarations :

```
[Header("Player's Survival Stats")]
public float maxHealth;
plublic float maxHunger, maxThirst;
public float thirstIncreaseRate, hungerIncreaseRate;
private float health, hunger, thirst;
```